# Force Nginx to redirect plain domain to index.php?

Tags: php, redirect, nginx, invision-power-board

I am currently running an IPS Community Suite forum on an Nginx server using EasyEngine and I have been trying to find a way to redirect http://example.com/ to http://example.com/index.php (only when it's simply the domain). Here is my current Nginx config for the server:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /var/www/example.com/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/example.com/key.key;

server_name example.com www.example.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log rt_cache;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;


root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

include common/wpfc.conf;
include common/wpcommon.conf;
include common/locations.conf;
include /var/www/classicaddons.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: ceejayoz, I've been having issues with the authentication and everything works properly when it's at http://example.com/index.php (or basically any page but http://example.com/). I just figured this would be the simplest solution for a fix.

Comment: That sounds like something you should investigate and fix instead of just patching over it with a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ($request_uri = "/") {
    return 301 "/index.php";
}
```

You can add this before including other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an exact match `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

```
location = / {
    return 301 /index.php;
}
```